# changing only one part of the template with angular 2 routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular2-routing

I have a template wit three sections one is the top navigation followed by left navigation and the content section which is the right div or element

```
<nav>top navs goes here </nav>
<div class="container>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3" id="left-nav">
left navs goes here
</div>
<div class="col-md-9" id="content">
  <!--Content goes here-->
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
</div>
```

The problem i am having right now is the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` which is supposed to replace the HTM inside the div with an id of content doesn't do so. instead it grabs all the HTML of the same template and place it inside `<div class="col-md-9" id="content">Content goes here</div>`. Why duplicate the same template is this the normal behavior or there is something wrong with my implementation?

Answer (score 0):

If you are changing just one part of your page one router-outlet is enough.
On the place that router-outlet is, component is injected. **What component is injected is defined by your routing configuration.** 
Also change:

```
<div class="col-md-9"> id="content"> 
to 
<div class="col-md-9" id="content">
```